# Calling node.NiceUrl gives me # in Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

Doing a project in Umbraco, and i've encountered problems in one case that when calling node.NiceUrl I get # as the result. What is weird though is that if i debug it somehow it resolves into the correct url.

```
var pages = Pages.Select((item, index) => new
{
    Url = item.NiceUrl,
    Selected = item.Id == currentPage.Id,
    Index = index
}).ToList();
```

Where Pages is obtained from:

```
CurrentPage.Parent.ChildrenAsList
```

Answer (score 3):

If I do it this way, it works, but I don't know why.

```
 Url = new Node(item.Id).NiceUrl,
```

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this error and it was because the id belonged to a media node.

Media is treated differently to other content and there's no easy way of getting the url because [different types of media store the url in different ways depending on context](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-1264).  That's why the NiceUrl function doesn't work for media (according to the umbraco developers).

My specific scenario was using images that had been selected using a media picker.  I got the url via the following code.  I wrapped it up in an extension method so you can consume it from a template in a convenient way.

```
public static string GetMediaPropertyUrl(this IPublishedContent thisContent, string alias, UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper = null)
{
    string url = "";

    if (umbracoHelper == null)
        umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);

    var property = thisContent.GetProperty(alias);

    string nodeID = property != null ? property.Value.ToString() : "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nodeID))
    {
        //get the media via the umbraco helper
        var media = umbracoHelper.TypedMedia(nodeID);

        //if we got the media, return the url property
        if (media != null)
            url = media.Url;
    }

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
    Url = umbraco.library.NiceUrl(Item.Id);
```

Comment: the library also has a method for retrieving the full url with the domain name, useful when sending out emails:
    string termsUrl = umbraco.library.NiceUrlWithDomain(1267);